# Trying to get mutliple inner joins in my sql

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

I'm using xampp with mysql and have been trying to format a query that uses inner joins on 4 seperate tables. The inner join contains the tables customer, bankaccounts, has and transactions. Has links the bank account and customer tables from M:N to 1:M while transactions is linked to bank accounts. I have attempted the following query:

```
SELECT t.TransactionID, 
       t.Description, 
       t.Amount, 
       t.isLoan, 
       t.TransactionDate, 
       a.AccountID, 
       a.SortCode, 
       a.Name, 
       a.CreationDate, 
       c.FirstName, 
       c.LastName 
       c.DateofBirth 
FROM transactions AS t 
INNER JOIN bankaccounts AS a
```

> #inner join will create a new table by combining the values selected based on if they satisfy the on condition below

```
 ON t.TransactionID IN ( SELECT t.TransactionID 
                            FROM transactions 
                            WHERE t.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2021-11-25' AND '2021-12-01'
                          )
AND t.AccountID = a.AccountID
INNER JOIN has ON has.AccountID = a.AccountID  ---- > #multiple inner joins can occur on multiple tables
INNER JOIN customers AS c ON has.CustomerID = c.CustomerID;
```

However this currently only gives an error.

What I need is to link together all the tables while ensuring that only transactions between those specific dates are picked.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the condition with the subquery to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t.TransactionID, t.Description, t.Amount, t.isLoan, t.TransactionDate, 
       a.AccountID, a.SortCode, a.Name, a.CreationDate, 
       c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.DateofBirth 
FROM transactions AS t 
INNER JOIN bankaccounts AS a ON t.AccountID = a.AccountID
INNER JOIN has ON has.AccountID = a.AccountID
INNER JOIN customers AS c ON has.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE t.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2021-11-25' AND '2021-12-01';
```

Comment: I just tried this however the issue still hasn't been resolved and it isn't really telling me why, it seems to not like how I'm calling the inner joins after defining what I want to select. "check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.DateofBirth FROM transactions AS t
INNER JOIN bankaccounts AS a ON t.Accou...' at line 1" is the specific error.

Comment: @RadioCode345 do you have a comma before c.DateofBirth?

Comment: No, I don't and trying to add one causes an error.

Comment: @RadioCode345 all columns in the select list must be separated by comma. Copy my code as it is and paste it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I realised there was a problem in my database, however copying and pasting solved the issue.